# FOSUser Bundle symfony2 date birthday

Tags: date, symfony, fosuserbundle

Hi i am using FOSUSerBundle for register. And also i added to my entity this:

```
    /**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="birthday", type="date", nullable=true, options={"default" = "0000-00-00"})
 */
protected $birthday="0000-00-00";
```

my register form have nothing with it. There is no birthday field or something like that. I just dont want to have 'null' at DB column.

But when i try  to register this error apear:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateType.php on line 44
```

How to fix it? :O

Answer (score 1):

Don`t use default = "0000-00-00", because Doctrine converts from and to PHP \DateTime. And PHP \DateTime has range between 1970 - ... Just use null for this reason.

Comment: and how could i achieve when someone register.. his default value in DB will not be NULL but 0000-00-00 ?

Answer (score 0):

It probably detects that `$birthday` property is not null when it tries to build datetime format before persisting it. Because your field has the value of type `string` but you field type is datetime it tries to perform format.

The solution would probably be to do:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="birthday", type="date", nullable=true, options={"default" = "0000-00-00"})
 */
protected $birthday=null;
```

Make sure that your database field is indeed nullable.

Hope this helps...

Comment: btw i forget mark your post in differnt question as asnswered. So i did now :) Hm.. on one hand it helped there is no error yet... but because $birthday=null the database is updated with value 'null'. I would like to see there the default value. Just this somehow make and we will be fine :)